# symfony button_to pass parameter

Tags: symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4, urlhelper

I have a button_to component in Symfony 1.4, which calls a route that receives a parameter (a slug). But I cannot get Symfony to recognize the parameter I'm sending. I have tried this same thing with a link_to and it works fine.

Here's my code:

routing.yml

```
entry_show:
  url:                /entry/:slug
  class:              sfDoctrineRoute
  options:
    model:            ProjectEntry
    type:             object
    method:           getEntryBySlug
  param:              { module: entry, action: show }
```

template:

```
<?php echo button_to('ButtonName', 'entry_show', array('slug' => 'this-is-my-slug')) ?>
```

Entry model:

```
public function getEntryBySlug($parameters)
{
  return $this->findOneBySlug($parameters['slug']);
}
```

All I get is the following 500 error:

> The "/entry/:slug" route has some
>   missing mandatory parameters (:slug).

I have also tried changing the template code with:

```
<?php echo button_to('ButtonName', 'entry_show?' . 'slug='.'this-is-my-slug') ?>
```

but to no avail...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo button_to('ButtonName', '@entry_show?slug=this-is-my-slug') ?>
```

You need the @ symbol to bind to a named route in the routing config, and the parameter `slug` is part of the URI argument, not the 3rd argument of the `button_to` function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set a default value for your slug parameter ?

Such as

```
  param:              { module: entry, action: show, slug: default-slug }
```

Comment: I've just tried this, but it doesn't makes any difference... Again, with link_to it works. What's the point with a default value in the routing config if I'm sending a value anyway?

Comment: Since after some Googling I found some forum topics telling that in such case a default value was missing for the parameter, I hoped that it would solve your problem : http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/74351/

Comment: BTW, what is the HTML code generated by the `button_to()` and `link_to()` helpers ? Could you find any difference which would explain your problem ?

Comment: button_to : <input slug="this-is-my-slug" value="ButtonName" type="button" onclick="document.location.href='/frontend_dev.php/entry/this-is-my-slug';" />

link_to : <a href="/frontend_dev.php/entry/this-is-my-slug">ButtonName</a>